# MacBook hangs when restarting to Vista through BootCamp

Tags: windows-vista, macbook, boot-camp

I have Vista Pro installed on my Macbook and while it mostly works well, sometimes when I select Windows from the boot screen after turning the thing on, the screen just goes black and it all stops. If I hold the power button until it powers down and repeat, it works.

It's not getting as far as Windows at all, I think, because if Windows was previously shut down to Hibernate, it still restores fine... and I'm pretty sure if Windows' startup had hung and been force-rebooted my session would be borked?

Answer (score 0):

Try [updating](http://support.apple.com/downloads/) your MacBook's EFI firmware. Applying the latest Boot Camp update (which is a pack of drivers, basically) also couldn't hurt.